# CSS give different look in mozila and chrome

Tags: html, css

CSs for rate box:

```
 .rating-input {
     font-size: 25px;
     position:relative;
     left:101%;
 }
```

Button:

```
 .custom-input-button {
     text-align: center;
     position:absolute;
     left:64.4%;
     top:12.1%;
 }
```

image :

```
 <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user_id; ?>/picture?type=large"
      style ="position:relative; top:-46px; left:0px;"/>
```

It gives different look in chrome and firefox:

[image: Image in chrome]

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

In chrome bookmark menu is not open. The change in spacing is due to that? 
I am frustrated changing the positions, but problem does not solved.

Comment: I would suggest making a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), with a basic example of the code you're using. You haven't given us enough information to be able to help.

Comment: @AdamBotley: These element are interconnected wit different js and function. SO I tried but in fiddle it does not give me sort of look in snap

Comment: I would avoid using values as 101%, 64.4%, 12.1%, -46px etc. I bet it won't look the same or good in every screen, window size or browser.

Comment: @drive235: Yes that is the main reason.But what is the solution for this? to position element I know this way only

Comment: You could make resizable containers with width in %. That will make your site adjustable to screen resolutions. Make it for minimum resolution of 15" display (1024px in width). Then position elements inside those containers. You can wrap them in another node of wrappers. More wrapper divs - the less can go wrong. But you don't want them too many, ofcourse. It depends on structure of your site. Then you can set margins and size of elements in px inside those containers.

Comment: @drive235: I dont want to use `px`. Only % is ok, can you please show me any example for that you said?

Comment: @cyclic Ok, if you want to use them. But only with % it will be tricky. Quick example. http://jsfiddle.net/Driveash/qgbLB/ You can also do extra css for specific browser.

Comment: @drive235: left and right could aslo be used in same manner `left:20%` etc, right?

Comment: @cyclic They could. Just position element according to wrapper that contains it.

Comment: @drive235: thanks a ton. And `left` and `margin-left` both are same or what?which one is better?

Comment: @cyclic left and margin-left could do the same thing but they are not the same. Left is for positioned element(as absolute, fixed). If you don't have positioned element then you want to use margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to sum up conversation in comments.

You could make resizable containers with width in %. That will make your site adjustable to screen resolutions. Make it for minimum resolution of 15" display (1024px in width). Then position elements inside those containers. You can wrap them in another node of wrappers. More wrapper divs - the less can go wrong. But you don't want them too many, ofcourse. It depends on structure of your site. Then you can set margins and size of elements in px inside those containers.

**Quick example of what babbling about in upper paragraph**

jsfiddle.net/Driveash/qgbLB
You can also make extra css for specific browser.

**Are left and margin-left the same?**

Left and margin-left could do the same thing but they are not the same. Left is for positioned element (as absolute, relative, fixed). If you don't have positioned element then you want to use margin-left.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that your not giving us enough code to really give you a good response to.

If this helps at all, when I do custom form boxes as such, I wrap them in a div to start off with.  Then define my widths/heights, and do a left float. This might be a deprecated method, and there may be a better way to do it, but this has always worked for me so I still tend to do it.

That should keep your elements all at the top, then you could do a clear:both, and float your rating system to the right?  Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

add `z-index:-999;` to the image so it doesn't sit in front of the green banner

Comment: what effect it created?